# Move established website from .CA to .COM?

Tags: seo

We have a well-established website which lives for 3 years and we got 10K organic traffic plus ads traffic each month, a lot of blog post is well ranked.

My question is what the best SEO practice to move the site from .CA to .COM? my boss thing if we move from .CA to .COM will get more traffic from US.

What is the best way to handle that without hurting any SEO?

Thanks,

Comment: Having a com will get you more US traffic because Google only shows. CA domains to people in Canada. Instead of moving it though, you should consider having the same site on both the CA domain and the.com domain. That's allowed by Google and is pretty much the best of both worlds. You'll get a ranking boost in Canada on the CA domain annual rank globally on the.com domain.

Comment: By doing that? will Google penalized all content as duplicate content? that will hurt both.CA and .COM site?

Comment: You can have multiple differently targeted sites to different countries that all have the same content and Google knows how to deal with it without penalizing for duplicate content.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen, we can't risk the chance if something happens if I clone the content from CA to COM, any official wordings from Google webmaster?

Comment: There is tons of documentation about this.   Search for "geo targeting" or "hreflang" along with terms like "search console", and "same language".   If you want to be safer about it, set the targeting for the `.com` site to just the United States so that it doesn't compete with the `.ca` site.   Google supports this because there often need to be differences for different countries: regional spellings, different currencies, different sales, different marketing, etc even when the vast majority of the content is exactly the same.